# how to convert world coordinates to screen coordinates

Tags: c++, directx-11, coordinate-transformation

I am creating a game that will have 2d pictures inside a 3d world.

I originally started off by not caring about my images been stretched to a square while I learnt more about how game mechanics work... but it's now time to get my textures to display in the correct ratio and... size.

Just a side note, I have played with orthographic left hand projections but I noticed that you cannot do 3d in that... (I guess that makes sense... but I could be wrong, I tried it and when I rotated my image, it went all stretchy and weirdosss).

the nature of my game is as follows:

[image]

In the image it says -1.0 to 1.0... i'm not fussed if the coordinates are:

- topleft = 0,0,0
- bottom right = 1920, 1200, 0

But if that's the solution, then whatever... *(p.s the game is not currently set up so that -1.0 and 1.0 is left and right of screen. infact i'm not sure how i'm going to make the screen edges the boundaries (but that's a question for another day)*

---

**Question:**

The issue I am having is that my image for my player (2d) is **128 x 64** pixels. After world matrix multiplication (I think that's what it is) the vertices I put in scale my texture hugely... which makes sense but it looks butt ugly and I don't want to just whack a massive scaling matrix into the mix because it'll be difficult to work out how to make the texture 1:1 to my screen pixels (although maybe you will tell me it's actually how you do it but you need to do a clever formula to work out what the scaling should be).

But basically, **I want the vertices to hold a 1:1 pixel size of my image**, unstretched...

So I assume I need to convert my world coords to screen coords before outputting my textures and vertices??? I'm not sure how it works...

Anyways, here are my vertices.. you may notice what I've done:

```
struct VERTEX
{
    float X, Y, Z;
    //float R, G, B, A;
    float NX, NY, NZ;
    float U, V;          // texture coordinates
};

const unsigned short SquareVertices::indices[ 6 ] = {
    0, 1, 2,    // side 1
    2, 1, 3
};

const VERTEX SquareVertices::vertices[ 4 ] = {
        //{ -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f },    // side 1
        //{ 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f },
        //{ -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f },
        //{ 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,       0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f }

    { -64.0f, -32.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },    // side 1
    { 64.0f, -32.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f },
    { -64.0f, 32.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 64.0f, 64.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }
};
```

(128 pixels / 2 = 64 ), ( 64 / 2 = 32 ) because the centre is 0.0... but what do I need to do to projections, world transdoobifications and what nots to get the worlds to screens?

My current setups look like this:

```
// called 1st
void Game::SetUpViewTransformations( )
{
    XMVECTOR vecCamPosition = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f, 0 );
    XMVECTOR vecCamLookAt = XMVectorSet( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    XMVECTOR vecCamUp = XMVectorSet( 0, 1, 0, 0 );
    matView = XMMatrixLookAtLH( vecCamPosition, vecCamLookAt, vecCamUp );
}

// called 2nd
void Game::SetUpMatProjection( )
{
    matProjection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(
        XMConvertToRadians( 45 ),                                      // the field of view
        windowWidth / windowHeight,  // aspect ratio
        1,                                                           // the near view-plane
        100 );                                                        // the far view-plan
}
```

and here is a sneaky look at my update and render methods:

```
// called 3rd
void Game::Update( )
{
    world->Update();
    worldRotation = XMMatrixRotationY( world->rotation );

    player->Update( );
    XMMATRIX matTranslate = XMMatrixTranslation( player->x, player->y, 0.0f );
    //XMMATRIX matTranslate = XMMatrixTranslation( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    matWorld[ 0 ] = matTranslate;
}

// called 4th
void Game::Render( )
{
    // set our new render target object as the active render target
    d3dDeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, rendertarget.GetAddressOf( ), zbuffer.Get( ) );

    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
    float color[ 4 ] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
    d3dDeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView( rendertarget.Get( ), color );
    d3dDeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView( zbuffer.Get( ), D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0 ); // clear the depth buffer

        CBUFFER cBuffer;
        cBuffer.DiffuseVector = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
        cBuffer.DiffuseColor = XMVectorSet( 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f );
        cBuffer.AmbientColor = XMVectorSet( 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f );
        //cBuffer.Final = worldRotation * matWorld[ 0 ] * matView * matProjection;
        cBuffer.Final = worldRotation * matWorld[ 0 ] * matView * matProjection;
        cBuffer.Rotation = XMMatrixRotationY( world->rotation );

        // calculate the view transformation
        SetUpViewTransformations();
        SetUpMatProjection( );

            //matFinal[ 0 ] = matWorld[0] * matView * matProjection;

            UINT stride = sizeof( VERTEX );
            UINT offset = 0;

                d3dDeviceContext->PSSetShaderResources( 0, 1, player->texture.GetAddressOf( ) ); // Set up texture
                d3dDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, player->vertexbuffer.GetAddressOf( ), &stride, &offset ); // Set up vertex buffer
                d3dDeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST ); // How the vertices be drawn
                d3dDeviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer( player->indexbuffer.Get( ), DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0 ); // Set up index buffer
                d3dDeviceContext->UpdateSubresource( constantbuffer.Get( ), 0, 0, &cBuffer, 0, 0 ); // set the new values for the constant buffer

                d3dDeviceContext->OMSetBlendState( blendstate.Get( ), 0, 0xffffffff ); // DONT FORGET IF YOU DISABLE THIS AND YOU WANT COLOUR, * BY Color.a!!!
                d3dDeviceContext->DrawIndexed( ARRAYSIZE( player->indices ), 0, 0 ); // draw

    swapchain->Present( 1, 0 );
}
```

---

Just to clarify, if I make my vertices **use 2 and 1 respective of the fact my image is 128 x 64**.. I get a normal looking size image.. and yet at 0,0,0 it's not at 1:1 size... wadduuuppp buddyyyy

```
    { -2.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f },    // side 1
    { 2.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f },
    { -2.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f },
    { 2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f }
```

Desired outcome 2 teh max:

[image]

Cool picture isn't it :D ?

**Comment help:**

[image]

Comment: Isn't it counterproductive to render in 3D but have to transform it back so there is no scaling? Couldn't you just render it 2D in the first place?

Comment: I've got 3d rotations going on the 2d characters... A bit like paper Mario :) (and also, this is but the start of the game...) ... For now, I have set the Vertices to 2.0f and 1.0f in respect to 128 / 2 being 64... unfortunately the texture is still scaled like a rats ass, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Hmm. Could you perhaps post a screenshot of the symptoms? Also, you can still rotate with an orthographically projection. All a perspective projection done is make farther objects smaller, which does not seem to be what you want in this case.

Comment: Updated @BWG - and thanks for tuning in brah! and a bit more too...

Comment: So sorry. The one on the right is too big, or the one on the left? Also, this problem is taking my mind off an english paper :P

Comment: the one on the left is too big, it should be small like the right one... oh god now I have woken up afresh this morning I can see how the image is confusing. the right one is 1:1 pixels (well its not in this image but for all intents and purposes), the other has been scaled up by my non screen coordinatiness

Comment: @BWG - I removed the projection matrix and set my vertices to the coorect coorindates, looks great. but the rotation ofcourse does not work without projection... and when I add projection they grow in size again. any ideas?

Comment: It should still work to rotate without projection. What ortho matrix are you calling?

Comment: Literally just applying this now: 
 matView = XMMatrixOrthographicLH( Window::width, Window::height, -1.0, 1.0 ); ... when my character does the flip, it just cuts him up till he's a line then as he rotates back around the other way, he goes to full width again.

Comment: "Cuts him up till he's a line ... rotates back the other way... goes to full width again" What do you mean by 'cuts him up till he's a line? And what are you expecting to happen? Sorry if I'm not much help.

Comment: No worries, have you ever seen Paper Mario... it's Mario in 2d.. but when he turns, it's as if he's a bit of cardboard.. and he's flipped.. so the perspective of 3d becomes apparent when he's flipping around.. i've included an image at end of OP

Comment: I'm not really sure what to say :'(

Comment: I found this, it's relevant.. I will keep you updated on how I get on: http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/rayproj.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familliar with direct-x but as far as I can see the thing with your image that is screen coordinates are [-1...+1] on x and y. So total length on both axis equals 2 and your image is scaled times 2. Try consider this scale in camera matrix.